# How can I use a JSON file such as a database to store new and old objects?

Tags: python, json, django, python-requests

I get the JSON objects from one of the sites and I want to attach these objects into a JSON file. the task is: I want to use JSON file as a database to save all information from the site I get objects from it so, the data I will show it breaking into 2 data which titled by the date like so:

- first: will be new data that will appear in the news.html
- second: will be old data that will appear in the old.html

the problems that I'm facing are, which file handling I have to use (r, a, w)?
of course, will not be r because I want data to be written when new data comes from the request so, in this case, I should use (a or, w), but if I used **w** will override all data that exists in JSON file.

and if I used **a** I will face 3 challenges in every request process I do:

1. the main curly braces will repeat with new data that appended to File but I need to repeat data into the main curlies itself.
2. curly braces will not be separated by a comma.
3. in every request process that occurs by reloading the page will be repeated the same objects so, one object will repeat more than one time.

so, my questions are:

- how can I append data and avoid the 3 problems I defined above?
- which file handling I have to use?

  ````
  import requests
  import json
  import datetime
  import re```


  def response(request):
      now = datetime.datetime.now()
      date_now = "{}-{}-{}".format(now.year, now.month, now.day)
      url = "http://newsapi.org/v2/everything"
      params = {
          'q': 'bitcoin',
          'from': date_now,
          'sortBy': 'publishedAt',
          'apiKey': '1186d3b0ccf24e6a91ab9816de603b90'
      }
      response = requests.request("GET", url, params=params)
      return response


  def index(request):
      now = datetime.datetime.now()
      date_now = "{}-{}-{}".format(now.year, now.month, now.day)
      res = response(request)
      # all news
      arr_data = []
      for news in res.json()['articles']:
          publishedAt = re.match("\d+-\d+-\d+", news['publishedAt'])
          rm_words = news['content'].split()[:-2] or None
          content = " ".join(rm_words)
          data = {
              publishedAt.group(): {
                  "source": news['source'],
                  "title": news['title'],
                  "describe": news['description'],
                  "url": news['url'],
                  "urlImage": news['urlToImage'],
                  "content": content
              }
          }
          arr_data.append(data)

      spec_data = []
      with open('data.json', "w+") as fp:
          json.dump(arr_data, fp, indent=4)
      for data in json.load(open("data.json", "r")):
          spec_data.append(data)
      context = {
          'data': spec_data,
          'date_now': date_now
      }
      return render(request, 'news/news.html', context)


  def old_news(request):
      now = datetime.datetime.now()
      date_now = "{}-{}-{}".format(now.year, now.month, now.day)
      res = response(request)
      # all news
      arr_data = []
      for news in res.json()['articles']:
          publishedAt = re.match("\d+-\d+-\d+", news['publishedAt'])
          rm_words = news['content'].split()[:-2] or None
          content = " ".join(rm_words)
          data = {
              publishedAt.group(): {
                  "source": news['source'],
                  "title": news['title'],
                  "describe": news['description'],
                  "url": news['url'],
                  "urlImage": news['urlToImage'],
                  "content": content
              }
          }
          arr_data.append(data)

      spec_data = []
      with open('data.json', "w+") as fp:
          json.dump(arr_data, fp, indent=4)
      for data in json.load(open("data.json", "r")):
          spec_data.append(data)
      context = {
          'data': spec_data,
          'date_now': date_now
      }
      return render(request, 'news/old_news.html', context)
  ````

Comment: The first principle with files containing `json` is that by convention the file contains exactly *one* `json` object or list. If you have some extra data that you want to add to the file, then you must create exactly *one* object or list and write it to the file in one go. I suggest you read the file in one go to get a python `dict` or `list`, update it with new information and write the whole thing back again.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use both read and write modes to fulfill this task.

First you have to read the current content of the file by using the read state and then store them in a variable.

```
try:
with open('data.json') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
```

Next, update the variable with the values you need.

```
json_data['new_key'] = []
json_data['new_key'].append("1")
```

Finally, you have to write to the file with the current content and the old content.

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_data, outfile)
```

Optional Step if the JSON file is empty:

```
import json
try:
    with open('data.json') as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json_data = {}
        json.dump(json_data, outfile)
```

Comment: I'm trying to apply your suggestion but it has failed or perhaps I miss understand in point so, let's say that JSON file that I want to write some object into it empty so, in this case, I cannot use json.load() in the beginning of a code but I should use dump instead to fill objects in it. hence, where I have to use load. so, please could you tell me more for clear!?

Comment: In that case, you can use a try-except block to handle that. I updated my answer with the code.